# Database table structure: Venues and categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have a list of venues and a list of categories like bar, nightclub, restaurant, cafe, disco etc. I need to pair all venue with their corresponding category.

One venue may belong to one or many categories:

venue, category
Venue A | bar, restaurant
Venue B | nightclub
Venue C | cafe, restaurant
Venye D | disco

Now, how do I structure this properly?
I seems a comma separated list in the categories column is not the right way to go.
I'm using MondoDB btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
  {
    venue: 'Some Nightclub',
    categories: ['bar', 'nightclub']
  },
  {
    venue: 'Some Cafe',
    categories: ['cafe', 'disco']
  }
]
```

Comment: Add some comments around this to improve the quality of the answer, explaining what you've done and why you've done it. In review of a flag someone raised about this post, I'm picking "Looks OK", because I don't see a need to delete this.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As each venue can have many categories, and each category can have many venues, this is called a M:N relationship.

In this case, here's the schema I'd use, based on a pattern featured in the book [MongoDB Applied Design Patterns](http://books.google.com/books?id=S53RrxZZMtcC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=mongodb%20product%20multiple%20categories&source=bl&ots=6xy8qbkyux&sig=zHWcMc2nGz1X-lAhaOSZGR9smKo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uj0zVJTdJ8TWaqWZgfgI&ved=0CB0Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=mongodb%20product%20multiple%20categories&f=false) (link points to the right page):

```
//db.venue.schema
[
  { "_id": "Venue A",
    "category_ids": ["bar","restaurant",...]
  }
]

// db.category.schema
[
  { 
    "_id": "bar"
  },
  {
    "_id": "restaurant"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Why would you add a separate Schema with the categories? They are already listed in the "category_ids". Does this make it easier to query?

Comment: you could have more attributes to a category than just its name. For example, if in the future you want to add a 'description', or a 'type', to a category, you will have a much easier time. here the value in category_ids should be seen as an ID refering to a category object